# Short story from 60's or before about building infinite energy source from rubbish pile

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

The part I remember is that, possibly after a UFO or similar sighting,  a farm-hand/individual suddenly puts together a machine that is self powered from the resources of the rubbish pile (metals etc) (by a barn?).

This astonishes the army, generals etc; at the end he disassembles it before they find out how it works.

The phrase I think I remember is that at the end:

> He quietly said "whee"!

Comment: I remember reading that story, so I can confirm that it exists and you've got the last line at least approximately right, but I'm afraid that's all I remember.

Answer (score 10):

The story is ["The Available Data on the Worp Reaction"](http://books.google.com/books?id=1M0Y2RYqffIC&lpg=PA174&ots=T2EgCiqZrt&dq=The%20Available%20Data%20on%20the%20Worp%20Reaction&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q=The%20Available%20Data%20on%20the%20Worp%20Reaction&f=false) (Google Books) by Lion Miller. 
An [audio version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGU-65qMRJE) of the story is currently available on YouTube.

The last paragraph of the story:

> Now, unmoved be an occasional berating by L. S. Worp, silent before an infrequent official interrogation, Aldous Worp sits on a box in the back yard of his ancestral home, gazing serenely out over the city dump.  Once in a very great while his eyes light up for a moment and he says "Whee!" very quietly.

Comment: I remember "The Available Data on the Worp Reaction" well The last paragraph quoted is as I recall it, and remember that L.S. Worp that "each piece fitted together tighter than a duck's..." The device emitted a purple light from underneath when Aldous Worp climbed on it and operated some kind of a wheel or handle to make it lift. A very enjoyable short story. Whee!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for [Robot AL-76 Goes Astray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_AL-76_Goes_Astray), by Isaac Asimov, collected in *The Rest Of The Robots* (and, I suspect, a lot of [other books](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44198)).

A robot intended for mining on the Moon gets lost on Earth; it attempts to perform its mining job, and puts together its own mining equipment from junk parts that it scavenges. It comes up with something that's a lot more efficient than the standard equipment - from memory, it demolishes a mountain using something powered by a small battery.

In the end, the robot is ordered to forget what it did, which it does, all too literally.

> But this Disinto worked differently. I went through the rubbish with a
> microscope, and would you like to see the only source of power of any
> kind that I found?"
>
> "What was it?"
>
> "Just this! And we'll never know how he did it." And Austin Wilde held
> up the source of power that had enabled a Disinto to chew up a
> mountain in half a second, two flashlight batteries!

You can read the full story online [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/39205165/Robot-AL-76-Goes-Astray);